# DotNet Core 2.1 Custom Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I created a custom exception and I would like to add few more but I cannot get it to work properly.

This is 1 exception

```
[Serializable]
public class GoogleAuthenticationException : Exception
{
    public GoogleAuthenticationException() { }
    public GoogleAuthenticationException(string message)
        : base(message) { }
    public GoogleAuthenticationException(string message, Exception inner)
        : base(message, inner) { }
}
```

In my Startup I use

```
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Identity/Error");
```

Then in my Error.cshtml.cs.  I would like to identify the custom exception and then do some things based on the exception type (GoogleAuthenticationException)

```
[ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
public void OnGet()
{
    var exceptionHandler = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
    var exception = exceptionHandler?.Error as GoogleAuthenticationException;

    if (exception is GoogleAuthenticationException)
        //Do Some Stuff -- But I can never make it here
    else if (exception is AnotherCustomException)
        //Do Some OtherStuff 

    RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier;
}
```

It seems to be something simple that I am missing but I am not sure.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

When I debug the Exception is always null and I can never continue to do stuff based on the Exception type (GoogleAuthenticationException)

Comment: where is it failing?

Comment: I does not fail I just cannot verify that the type is GoogleAuthenticationException  so I can never get to the part "Do Some Stuff"

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint and looked at `exceptionHandler?.Error` in the debugger?

Comment: Yes, exception is null, but exceptionHandler.Error has a system Exception with all the correct details.

Comment: The 'as' keyword will return null if the conversion isn't successful, in other words exceptionHandler.Error cannot be converted to a type of GoogleAuthenticationException. You need to actually throw the GoogleAuthenticationException somewhere, you can test that by simply adding "throw GoogleAuthenticationException;" before your if statement.

Comment: I am throwing the exception like this: throw new GoogleAuthenticationException("Error Message"); but by the time it gets to the error page it is a System.Exception and I cannot convert it to a GoogleAuthenticationException.  Am I missing something on the class.  I think I got everything, and I am inheriting from Exception... So I am not sure what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

OK I knew it was something simple... The GoogleAuthenticationExcepttion was actually the inner exception from the System.Exception.  Thanks jmdon and Kirk Larkin for the quick responses and guidance.

Updated Code:

```
var exceptionHandler = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();
var exception = exceptionHandler?.Error?.InnerException as GoogleAuthenticationException;
```